# Exclude string from MongoDB regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

My documents looks like this.

```
{
   "sId": "s1",
   "source": "September Challenge %2s",
},
{
   "sId": "s2",
   "source": "September 2019 Challenge %2s"
},
{
   "sId": "s3",
   "source": "September Challenge 2019"
}
```

I was trying to find the documents by searching in `source` with regex `2`.
I am getting all the 3 documents. I want the result below.

```
{
   "sId": "s2",
   "source": "September 2019 Challenge %2s"
},
{
   "sId": "s3",
   "source": "September Challenge 2019"
}
```

first documents should be ignored because it has `%2s`, Second and third documents should come because it contains `2019`.
Can anyone please guide me how I can achieve the above.

Comment: Why wouldn't the second document be ignored?

Comment: In second document `2019` is there in `source`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below regex.

```
db.getCollection('somecollection').find({field: {$regex: '(?<!%)<word>(?!=s)'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems like you want to find documents with `2019` in the `source` field, even if it contains `%2`. You can do this with a more specific regex.

```
db.collection.find({ source: { $regex: "2019" } })
```

Comment: Thanks :), but I am not specific to `2019`, it might be `2` or `0` or `9` or `september`  anything. There are lot of documents contains `%2s`, I want to ignore documents which contains `%2s` but  in case of second document, if i search with `2` or `september` it should not be ignored.