# Exclude entities with given string from MongoDB find with RegExp

Tags: regex, mongodb

My documents looks like this.

```
{
   "sId": "s1",
   "source": "September Challenge 1"
},
{
   "sId": "s2",
   "source": "other string multi word"
},
{
   "sId": "s3",
   "source": "September sub string to filter Challenge"
}
```

I was trying to find the documents only without substring " sub string to filter ".
The expected result is:

```
{
   "sId": "s1",
   "source": "September Challenge 1"
},
{
   "sId": "s2",
   "source": "other string multi word"
},
```

Which regexp should I use?

I have tried different regexps but haven't achive the expected result.
I saw [Exclude string from MongoDB regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031333/exclude-string-from-mongodb-regex), but I failed to adapt the answer to my situation.

Comment: is it a substring always and not some pattern

Comment: not query? https://mongoplayground.net/p/LnMiXnOMpMP

Answer (score 0):

RegExp-only solution is:

```
db.collection.find({
  source: {
    "$regex": "^(?=.*1)((?! sub string to filter ).)*$"
  }
})
```

Actually, the question is the same as [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)